# Python how to skip the first (i.e. zero) iteration using enumerate and a list?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a table object.

I want to check to see if the first row has the value of `Test`, in which case I need to do something with each row in the table.

Otherwise, if the first row does not have the value of `Test` I need to skip that row and do something with rows 1 and on.

Because I need both the index and the row, I have to use enumerate, but it seems like I am using it in a messy way.  Here I am calling `enumerate` twice and checking to see if the index is `0` twice.  Is there a more concise way to to this?

```
for i, r in enumerate(null_clipData.rows()):
    if r[0].val == 'Test':
        # Do something if the first row is Test
        for index, row in enumerate(null_clipData.rows()):
            if index == 0:
                continue # But do anything the first time (stay in this loop though)
            print(index, row)
        break # All through with test row

    if i == 0:
        continue # Don't do anything with the first row if the value was not Test

    print(i, r) # Do something with i and r
```

Comment: What happens if the *second* row has the value of `Test`?  It looks like that will trigger the same special processing you get if it's the first row.  In any event, I would recommend skipping the first row in the loop (handle it specially first) and using `enumerate(..., start=1)` to process the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Kevin’s advice, you can handle the first item separately, and then continue with the loop:

```
rows = iter(null_clipData.rows())

firstRow = next(rows)
specialHandling = firstRow.val == 'Test'

for i, r in enumerate(rows, start=1):
    if specialHandling:
        # do something special with r
    else:
        # do the normal stuff with r
```

Alternatively, you can also keep it in a single loop:

```
specialHandling = False # default case
for i, r in enumerate(null_clipData.rows()):
    if i == 0: # first item
        specialHandling = r == 'Test'
        continue

    if specialHandling:
        # do something special with r
    else:
        # do the normal stuff with r
```

Comment: sleek. Do you have a preference here, is one more Pythonic? I consistently forget to use `iter`

Comment: The former makes it look a bit more separated, so that might make your intention clearer. But I’d personally accept both solutions.

Comment: Also, in your second example, if `r == 'Test'` doesn't the `continue` statement skip over the `if specialHandling`?

Comment: Yes, the `continue` make it skip the remaining part of the loop body. You could also used an `elif specialHandling` there, but I wanted to make it clear that the handling of the first item is over there. And I’m skipping the rest, because I was assuming that you didn’t want to continue doing the “normal stuff” with the first row then.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't want to do the "normal stuff" but it seems like, for the first item, `specialHandling` is set to `True`, (because `r == 'Test'`) but then `continue `continues past the `if specialHandling` statement so I can never actually evaluate `if specialHandling`

Comment: Yes, but only for the first row. So the normal stuff at the bottom is always skipped for the first row. If you still want to handle the first row there, you can simply change it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
rows=null_clipData.rows()
enumeration=enumerate(rows[1:])
if rows[0]=='Test':
    for idx,row in enumeration:
        print(idx,row)
else:
    for i,r in enumeration:
        print (i,r)
```

Something like that?
I would  suggest that you factor out the two different for loops into their own functions, to keep it cleaner.

just noticed Poke's answer, that too :)

Comment: This assumes that `rows` is a sequence though.